# Joining PowerBI tables in a new Table

Tags: join, powerbi, data-analysis

I have multiple tables in power query editor named as CGTMSE_2020-21, CGTMSE_2021-22, CGTMSE_2022-23 etc. Table structure for all the tables are exactly similar. (One sample table is attached as screenshot).
My requirement is a table as per the following structure: (Financial Year is not present in the table column, but in the file name). Also I need the data only for one State. Is there any way in Power BI to implement this.

| Year | State | Number of Cases | Credit Amount | Claims Settled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-21 | ARUNACHAL PRADESH | 619 | 543 | 254 |
| 2021-22 | ARUNACHAL PRADESH | 230 | 143 | 136 |
| 2022-23 | ARUNACHAL PRADESH | 430 | 548 | 298 |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W87p.png)
Thanks in Advance

I tried using power Query Editor by transforming into tables, but couldnot write custom query to join specific rows from each table and appending to one new table.

Comment: No attachment - please provide and even better, provide the table structure in text form (search for "table to markdown" using your favourite search engine)

Answer (score 0):

1. For each of your queries (tables), add a Custom Column for `Year`
   and manual set its value.
2. Then select all three queries, and select `Append Queries as New` in the Home ribbon in `Combine` group.
3. In the new query, filter the State column.